# SEDE statistical model construction, how do I calculate the effect of the upvotes to the new content?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, data-explorer, statistics

I think we all know the endorphin produced by the Green Rectangle very well. Varying from our individual habit, mood, SE experience, and a lot others, I think we can agree it is a major force growing the Stack Exchange network.

I am thinking about a query what could measure how the upvotes are attracting new content. Ideally, the result would be a single floating point number, showing how many new posts are attracted by a single upvote.

I think the result would be a number somewhere between 0.1 and 1.0.

Now the problem is:

- The count of the new posts depends on a lot of things, and most of them can't be even calculated or it is not even known
- There is no way to know, what exactly motivated a post
- There could be very indirect effects, too (for example, think about this causality chain: more upvote increases repwhores -> repwhores generate LQ content -> LQ content distracts HQ users -> fewer HQ users decreases quality -> lower quality distracts visitors -> fewer visitors create fewer posts. In general, longer causality chains tend to have a lesser statistical effect, but there are more from them.)
- There is no way to know, and there isn't even a rough estimation of the characteristic time of the effects.

A possible way would be to simply measure a correlation coefficient between the count of the upvotes what a post got, and between the count of the posts what its OP posted after that. It could lead to an easily implementable SEDE query what could easily result this floating point number. My only problem is that I don't find its result very convincing, because:

- The SE is a continuously changing system, having an all-time stat doesn't say too much of how the SE behaves *now*.
- Many of the indirect effects simply can't be measured because they didn't yet happen.

So, my question in short: What exactly should I measure and how?

Is the SE making similar analysis of their data? If yes, how could they do this?

Comment: A potential problem with SEDE is that it only stores vote *dates*, not *timestamps* (for privacy reasons), so the granularity is rather course. Another interesting factor to consider is the daily reputation cap. Given enough upvotes, there's no green box anymore.

Comment: But (anecdotal evidence, I know), I remember discovering (only 6-8 weeks later) that [my first Meta SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297263/4751173) got a lot of upvotes. That inspired me to become a lot more active there.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks. My meta activity was mainly a continuous fight, I can't remember my first meta post, but it is likely long downvoted and deleted. Somewhere I've read an interesting stat (coming from a CM having access to deleted data), that the probability of the reoccurrence of first-posters depends mainly that they got an answer, or at least a comment. Surprisingly, even if an edit happened to their post, has a higher effect as its closure or voting count.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you very much!